# Problemas Con API de Age Of Empires

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

tengo un problema utilizando la API (https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/) quiero utilizarlo en un trabajo de React
me sale este error: "There's nothing here, yet".
y no se como solucionarlo, si alguien me ayuda lo agradecería

Comment: Eso no es un error, es simplemente un mensaje de que _ahí no hay nada, aún_. No olvides proveer un [repro].

Comment: Saludos, si estas comenzando con el desarrollo de software te recomiendo aprender ingles o mínimo usar un traductor al momento de ver los mensajes, alertas o errores que te muestra cierto lenguaje. ;)